# JavaScript extract JSON data into a new object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to extract multiple pieces of data out of a JSON file to put into an object, so that I can convert the object back to JSON with only the data I want.

I was thinking an object like this would be possible:

```
data = {
  0: {
    lat: xxxx,
    lng: xxxx,
    name: xxxx
  },
  1: {
    ...
  }
};
```

Here's the loop that extracts the data, but I can't figure out how to assign the three data points to the same object (data.0, data.1, ...) within the object (data).

```
for (let z = 0; z < data.features.length; z++) {
  finalData.z.lat = data.features[z].center[0];
  finalData.z.lng = data.features[z].center[1];
  finalData.z.name = data.features[z].text;
}
```

I don't mind if an array is used instead on an object as they can be JSON.stringified, too. The length of data.features varies depending on the API call.

I'm hoping to accomplish this using vanilla JS, but open to suggestions. It's being executed on the server (Node.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` notation which allows property access instead of `dot` notation.

```
var dataArray = [];

for (let z = 0; z < data.features.length; z++) {
  var finalData = {};
  finalData[z] = {};

  finalData[z].lat = data.features[z].center[0];
  finalData[z].lng = data.features[z].center[1];
  finalData[z].name = data.features[z].text;

  dataArray.push(finalData);
}
```

if you are using ES6, then you can use `[]` pattern matching to get the computed property names.

```
let dataArray = [];

for (let z = 0; z < data.features.length; z++) {
  let feature = data.features[z];
  let structuredData = {
        [z]: {
            lat: feature.center[0],
            lng: feature.center[1],
            name: feature.text
      }
  };

  dataArray.push(structuredData);
}
```

Comment: The first example didn't work, but the second one worked like a charm. The only thing I had to change was the semicolons to commas on lines 7 and 8, and remove the semicolon from the end of line 9. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MorganR My bad. Indeed they are supposed to be commas.